# SimpleInjector is throwing ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException when injecting delegates into services

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simple-injector

I am converting my ASP.Net application from MC3 to MVC4. I have Simpleinjector code from old MVC3 days as below

```
WebContainer.Instance.Container.GetInstance<Func<HttpRequestBase>>();
```

Now this line of code is throwing exception in the new SimpleInjector version 2.8.0. My application is in .Net framework 4.0. Please advise on the stack trace below

```
Message: No registration for type Func could be found.

Exception type: SimpleInjector.ActivationException
Stack Trace: 
at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowMissingInstanceProducerException(Type serviceType)
 at SimpleInjector.Container.GetInstance[TService]()
 at Aon.Exchange.Web.UserControlBase..ctor()
 at ASP.cmswebparts_aonexchange_help2_ascx..ctor()
 at __ASP.FastObjectFactory_app_web_help2_ascx_f5d8491b_aknegnyf.Create_ASP_cmswebparts_aonexchange_help2_ascx()
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(IWebObjectFactory objectFactory, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type t, Object[] parameters)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at CMS.PortalControls.CMSWebPartZone.LoadWebPart(Control container, CMSWebPartZone zone, WebPartInstance part, Boolean reloadData, Boolean isVariant)
```

The code for WebContainer is listed as below

```
     this.Container = new Container();
        SimpleInjectorWebInitializer.Initialize();
        this.Container.RegisterPackages(GetAssemblies());
        this.Container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        this.Container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();
        this.RegisterGlobalFilters();

        //this.Container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(this.Container));
        //this.VerifyPages();
```

The registration of this func is as below

```
 container.RegisterPerWebRequest<Func<HttpRequestBase>>(() => () => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request));
```

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? Can you show the registration you have for `Func<HttpRequestBase>`? The integration package for Simple Injector does not register this `Func<T>` for you.

Comment: Steven, thanks for your response. The registration looks as below      container.RegisterPerWebRequest<Func<HttpRequestBase>>(() => () => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request));

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version (v3.1).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you please confirm that this package is compatible with .Net framework 4 as I am not able to upgrade to 4.5 due to company policy.

Comment: I can confirm. Simple Injector v3 is compatible with .NET 4.0.

Comment: Steven, this issue has been resolved after the upgrade. I appreciate your help and taking the time to respond to me.

Comment: And what exactly was the problem? Did Simple Injector 3 throw an exception describing the problem?

Comment: I think there was a mix up of SimpleInjector 1.8 and 2.5 dlls. I started new solution and got error that the type Func<HttpRequestBase> has already been initialized. So I removed the statement and now I can get the solution to work as expected... I have to take a closer look at MVC4 pipleline .. thanks so much for your contribution